Inheritable and type-able SmartPointer class
I'm currently trying to create a custom SmartPointer class, different from the built in C++ smart pointers, that will do what I want. The goal is to be able to turn any class/struct into a smart pointer and have said class/struct be inheritable to where the smart pointer versions of the class are also inheritable.
For example, if I have class Parent which class ChildA and class ChildB inherit from, there will also be types Parentsp, ChildAsp, and ChildBsp. I want to be able to write functions that take the Parentsp as parameters but be able to pass ChildAsp or ChildBsp types to it. As in print(Parentsp p) and call it with ChildAsp and ChildBsp types. My current SmartPointer and RefCounter setup is the following.
class RefCounter {
  public:
    void AddRef() {count++;}
    int Release() {return --count;}

  private:
    int count;
};

template<typename T> 
class SmartPointer {
  public:
    SmartPointer() : mPtr(nullptr), mRef(nullptr) {
      mRef = new RefCounter();
      mRef->AddRef();
    }

    SmartPointer(T* mPtr) : mPtr(mPtr), mRef(nullptr) {
      mRef = new RefCounter();
      mRef->AddRef();
    }

    SmartPointer(const SmartPointer<T>& other) : mPtr(other.mPtr), mRef(other.mRef){
      mRef->AddRef();
    }

    ~SmartPointer(){
      if(mRef->Release() == 0) {
        delete mPtr;
        delete mRef;
      }
    }

    T& ptr(){
      return *mPtr;
    }

    T& operator*(){
      return *mPtr;
    }

    T* operator->(){
      return mPtr;
    }
    
    SmartPointer<T>& operator=(const SmartPointer<T>& other) {
      if (this != &other) {
        if(mRef->Release() == 0) {
          delete mPtr;
          delete mRef;
        }
        mPtr = other.mPtr;
        mRef = other.mRef;
        mRef->AddRef();
      }
      return *this;
    }

  private:
    T*    mPtr;
    RefCounter* mRef;
};

At the moment, I'm using the above with the following macro:
MAKE_SP(cls) typedef SmartPointer<cls> cls##sp
This gives me the SmartPointer type for the given class, but the inheritablitiy doesn't transfer. I've tried inheriting from SmartPointer<type> but that also doesn't work. I know inheriting from a SmartPointer is probably needed but I'm not sure how to go about it and keep my ability to typedef a type+sp type. Do I need a mid-class between SmartPointer and my other classes to inherit from? Do I need to step away from the template smart pointer?
EDIT 1:
From the answers I've gotten already, this is already possible with standard cpp shared pointers. For the sake of my question and my learning I want to create it from scratch.
Here's what I'm trying to do, which doesn't work:
#define MAKE_SP(cls) SmartPointer<cls> cls##sp /* or something similar */

class Parent;
MAKE_SP(Parent);
class Parent { ... }

class ChildA;
MAKE_SP(ChildA);
class ChildA : public Parent { ... }

class ChildB;
MAKE_SP(ChildB);
class ChildB : public Parent { ... }

void sp_func(Parentsp parent) { ... }

main() {
  ChildAsp c1 = new ChildAsp;
  sp_func(c1);
  ChildBsp c2 = new ChildBsp;
  sp_func(c2);
}


What you're describing is already possible with standard smart pointers

Sounds to me you are trying to reinvent the wheel. You can do everything that you want to do with classic smart pointers.

What would that look like? Also, I'm making it from scratch for the sake of getting a better understanding of smart pointers, so seeing a solution that works with what I have now would also be very helpful.

@SamKent Have a look at the answers you've received. I think looking into the documentation of smart pointers is a better way to go than trying to reinvent it.

std::unique_ptr<Base> = std::make_unique<Derived> or std::shared_ptr<Base> = std::make_shared<Derived>

I don't quite see how std::shared_ptr doesn't work for you; could you elaborate a bit more?

I want to be able to write functions that take the Parentsp as parameters but be able to pass ChildAsp or ChildBsp types to it.

So, this?
#include <memory>

class Parent
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Parent> Ptr;
};

class ChildA: public Parent
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<ChildA> Ptr;
};

void function(Parent::Ptr)
{
}

int main()
{
    ChildA::Ptr childA=std::make_shared<ChildA>();
    function(childA);

    return 0;
}

which compiles just fine:
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ -Wall Test.cpp
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $


Passing a smart pointer from a child class to an argument asking for a smart pointer to the parent class is already possible.
#include <memory>

class Parent {};
class Child : public Parent {};

void foo(const std::shared_ptr<Parent> &p) {}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::shared_ptr<Child> c = std::make_shared<Child>();
    foo(c);
}

https://godbolt.org/z/a8efo8YoW
If you want to re-implement it for fun it's fine but you should know it's already possible
